# Domain Validation Issue with TinyMCE in Capacitor.js App

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently working on integrating TinyMCE cloud-hosted version into a mobile application built using Capacitor.js. Everything works perfectly in the desktop environment, but I'm facing challenges on iOS. When testing on both the iOS simulator and an actual iPhone, I'm presented with a domain validation error message that reads: "We’re unable to check your domain because the referer header is missing. Please read the Guide on how to ensure your referer header is present, so we can then customize your editor experience."

Has anyone encountered a similar challenge when integrating TinyMCE into mobile or hybrid apps? Specifically:

Any insights on handling the "Referer" header in a Capacitor.js setting?
Recommendations or best practices for setting up TinyMCE in hybrid mobile environments like Capacitor.js?
Any guidance or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated!